# Commercial application that uses R portable and R packages

Tags: proprietary-code, package

I wrote an R script application that contains R packages and, mostly, my own code. I would like to sell the script as an application or as a gist (using `gist.github.com`) to be used by organizations that buy a subscription to run the script for their own needs. Some of the packages are GPL2, GPL3 or MIT.

1. Can I use the packages and just need to provide links to the packages on CRAN?
2. Do I have to release my code even if I didn't change anything in the packages content/code?
3. If my script run on a website,  do I need to provide the packages names that I use?
4. Can I install R-portable on my clients' computers in order for them to use my script.

Comment: Generally, if your application depends on GPL code, then you must release your application under compatible terms (you must release your own code and all source code you used). A subscription system is fine, but a subscriber must be free to modify and/or copy the code that she downloaded, even after the subscription ends.

Comment: 1. 3rd party links to a particular version may stop working; it is safer to offer the required source yourself. 2. Yes; whether you changed something does not matter for GPL. 3. No. 4. Yes.

Comment: @Brandin you don't have to release anything. The licence only says what you must do IF you release it.

Comment: The free software foundation would love you to sell software. As long as you do not take away the freedoms, check the licences.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor , can you please elaborate more on "you don't have to release anything"? Thanks.

Comment: @mql4beginner If you develop an application privately, based on GPL code, then no, you don't have to release your source code. But if you publish software which depends on GPL code, (such as offering it for download via a subscription) then you need to adhere to the GPL license terms to those that you published it to. In this case it means that your subscription customers must have the right to a copy of your source code on request, and they must also have the right to give/sell the software to a third party. Third parties also receive the right to a copy of the source code on request.

Comment: @mql4beginner what Brandin said. The rational is that you need to have all of the freedoms, in all situations. Being in a situation where you can not share, should not take away freedoms. Including the freedom to use for any purpose e.g. secret usage, with modification; or off-line usage. Therefore we don't need to share, but if we do …